# C# Count removed nodes

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have a xml file and I want to remove some of the nodes if they are duplicate. I want to remove the placemark which could be either in Document node or in Folder node. I also want to find how many were removed so I wrote this code

```
                var xDoc = XDocument.Load(kmlFileUrl);
                XNamespace ns = "http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2";

                var countInFolder = xDoc.Root
                .Elements(ns + "Document")
                .Elements(ns + "Folder")
                .Elements(ns + "Placemark")
                .GroupBy(i => (string)i)
                .SelectMany(g => g.Skip(1)).Count();

                xDoc.Root
                .Elements(ns + "Document")
                .Elements(ns + "Folder")
                .Elements(ns + "Placemark")
                .GroupBy(i => (string)i)
                .SelectMany(g => g.Skip(1))
                .Remove();

                var countInDocument = xDoc.Root
               .Elements(ns + "Document")                   
               .Elements(ns + "Placemark")
               .GroupBy(i => (string)i)
               .SelectMany(g => g.Skip(1)).Count();

                xDoc.Root
               .Elements(ns + "Document")                   
               .Elements(ns + "Placemark")
               .GroupBy(i => (string)i)
               .SelectMany(g => g.Skip(1))
               .Remove();

                int totalRemoved = int.Parse(countInFolder.ToString()) + int.Parse(countInDocument.ToString());
```

Can you please check and suggest if this code could be further improved or I can combine some of the lines in code or is this the correct way to remove and count them.

Edit: The xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">

  <Document>
    <name>KML Samples</name>
    <open>1</open>
    <description>Unleash your creativity with the help of these examples!</description>

    <Folder>
      <Placemark>
        <name>1</name>
        <description>abc</description>
        <Point>
          <coordinates>102.595626,14.996729</coordinates>
        </Point>
      </Placemark>
      <Placemark>
        <name>2</name>
        <description>abc</description>
        <Point>
          <coordinates>102.595626,14.996729</coordinates>
        </Point>
      </Placemark>
      <Placemark>
        <name>2</name>
        <description>abc</description>
        <Point>
          <coordinates>102.595626,14.996729</coordinates>
        </Point>
      </Placemark>
      <Placemark>
        <name>4</name>
        <description>abc</description>
        <Point>
          <coordinates>102.595626,14.996729</coordinates>
        </Point>
      </Placemark>
    </Folder>

    <Folder>
      <Placemark>
        <name>3</name>
        <description>abc</description>
        <Point>
          <coordinates>102.595626,14.996729</coordinates>
        </Point>
      </Placemark>
      <Placemark>
        <name>4</name>
        <description>abc</description>
        <Point>
          <coordinates>102.595626,14.996729</coordinates>
        </Point>
      </Placemark>
      <Placemark>
        <name>4</name>
        <description>abc</description>
        <Point>
          <coordinates>102.595626,14.996729</coordinates>
        </Point>
      </Placemark>
    </Folder>

    <Placemark>
      <name>4</name>
      <description>abc</description>
      <Point>
        <coordinates>102.595626,14.996729</coordinates>
      </Point>
    </Placemark>

    <Placemark>
      <name>4</name>
      <description>abc</description>
      <Point>
        <coordinates>102.595626,14.996729</coordinates>
      </Point>
    </Placemark>    

  </Document>
</kml>
```

Edit 2: I want to simply this. How do I ensure that all Placemark modes which are duplicates are removed from the xml file irrespective of which node they come in ie. it can be inside folder node or document node or anywhere so I want to remove all the duplicate ones.

Comment: Why are you converting the existing `int` value to a string and then parsing it for each part? The repeated code is unnecessary too. But fundamentally, if you want a review of working code, codereview.stackexchange.com is probably a better fit.

Comment: Suggestions for improvement are not on topic on Stack Overflow (too broad). If this is working code, try your luck at [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would improve your code:

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(kmlFileUrl);
XNamespace ns = "http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2";

var elementsInFolder = xDoc.Root
    .Elements(ns + "Document")
    .Elements(ns + "Folder")
    .Elements(ns + "Placemark")
    .GroupBy(i => (string) i)
    .SelectMany(g => g.Skip(1))
    .ToList();

var countInFolder = elementsInFolder.Count;
elementsInFolder.Remove();

var elementsInDocument = xDoc.Root
    .Elements(ns + "Document")
    .Elements(ns + "Placemark")
    .GroupBy(i => (string) i)
    .SelectMany(g => g.Skip(1))
    .ToList();

var countInDocument = elementsInDocument.Count;
elementsInDocument.Remove();

int totalRemoved = countInFolder + countInDocument;
```

Just save temporary results to List, before counting and deleting them. Also, there is no sense to convert integer to string and parse it, just use your integers as desired.

Comment: Thank you rattrapper. Your solution works. Do you think ToList() will consume more memory?

Comment: It will, but very small amout of memory. You can remove `ToList` calls, if you want, but storing results in a list will save time for processor